# Typeahead.js cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, typeahead.js

So I have a page that I am working on that is using the example form Typeahead.js page. It works just fine when I use the json file in the example located here: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/repos.json

However when I use my own JSON located here: http://www.irishcentral.com/templates/ta-articles.json I get an error "cannot read property 'length' of undefined". From what I have read that is because the JSON is invalid but I checked my JSON against two validators and they both say its valid. Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="CustomTemplate">
    <input class="example-irish typeahead" type="text" placeholder="" />
</div>

<script src="$cms.include("handlebars.js").url"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="$cms.include("typeahead.bundle.js").url"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var repos = new Bloodhound({
          datumTokenizer: function(d) { return d.tokens; },
          queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
          prefetch: '/templates/repos.json'
        });

        repos.initialize();

        $('.CustomTemplate .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
          name: 'twitter-oss',
          displayKey: 'title',
          source: repos.ttAdapter(),
          templates: {
            suggestion: Handlebars.compile([
              '<p class="repo-language">{{author}}</p>',
              '<p class="repo-name">{{title}}</p>',
              '<p class="repo-description">{{summary}}</p>'
            ].join(''))
          }
        });
     });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the path you specify at prefetch is wrong. Try replacing `prefetch: '/templates/repos.json'` with the following `prefetch: '/templates/ta-articles.json'`.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out and the problem was in the JSON. The JSON did not have a tokens element in it so calling d.tokens made it throw an error. I changed it to a tag I had in the json "title" and it works just fine now!